# Is KivyMD 2.0 theme support broken or perhaps does not act the same way?

Tags: kivymd

I spent a few hours getting my KivyMD 1.2 app running on 2.0 and it works now but the colors are horrible. I tried setting and changing palate and I can see that the App is accepting my new palate string but none of the widgets are changing.
My 1.2 app has a palate changer screen which works as expected but I have been unable to get 2.01 Dev0 to change  colors on anything. Is this broken or have they changed what the palate setting is supposed to do?
I tried running the custom color example too and could not get that to visibly change palate either.

Here is what I am setting:

```
class myApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # changing style works but primary_palate makes no color changes to any of the Widgets in my app!
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        # self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
```

Few of my widgets set color so changing the palate in 1.2 is very noticeable. Should 2.0 act similarly?